# How do I get single Post sub-category for specific parent in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I have an article categorized like this:

Countries (parent) >| Spain (child)

System (parent) >| Android (child)

I want to get the name of the country only with PHP ?

Comment: Have you considered using Custom Taxonomies. It looks like that would suit your situation more.

Comment: Yes I tried it but I found a problem with its slug, it gives me an error page